# css floating divs minwidth without overlapping

Tags: css, css-float

Well I am making a "simple 3 column layout", the basic setup are two fixed width columns and a (center) column that stretches to fill the remaining width.

Now there is a small "addon" to that simple layout: I wish to have a defined minimum width for the center column, css has an attribute for that so it seemed easy:

```
.content div {
  border:1px solid #bbb;  
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.content-left {
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
}

.content-main {
  margin-left: 200px;
  margin-right: 200px;
  min-width: 200px
}

.content-right {
  float: right;
  width: 200px;
}
```

However this gave an important problem: the moment the main column hits the "minimum width" (test it by dragging the dividers in the test link below), it starts overlapping with the left and right column. - I would actually like it to stretch the page introducing a horizontal scrollbar.

[fiddle to test it](http://jsfiddle.net/nw6b2y0a/3/)

Comment: Can you set `min-width` on `body`?

Comment: @jhpratt Well I prefer not to. This is part of a SPA, so setting a hard limit on body might destroy other pages that are routed to the body.

Comment: Ah, ok. Was just thinking super simple solution that takes next to zero effort. Definitely don't want to do that in your case, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it:

```css
[layout] {
  display: flex;
}
#left {
  flex: 0 0 180px;
  background-color:#f00;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
#right {
  flex: 1 0 300px;
  background-color:#0ff;
}
```

```html
<div layout>
    <div id="left">
        left
    </div>
    <div id="right">
        right
    </div>
</div>
```

See [`flex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex) for details. It's `flex-shrink` and `flex-grow` that do the heavy lifting in this case. And the default value of `flex-wrap`, which is `nowrap`.

Don't forget to [`prefix`](https://autoprefixer.github.io/).

Also note the `300px` value of `flex-basis` (third value in `flex` shorthand of `#right` element. In this case, it's the minimum width of that element. When it gets under that size, the scrollbar appears.

And here it is with 3 columns:

```css
[layout] {
  display: flex;
}
[layout] > * {
  padding: 1rem;
}
#left, #right {
  flex: 0 0 180px;
}
#left {
  background-color:#f00;
}
#right {
  background-color:#0ff;
}
#middle {
  flex: 1 0 300px;
  margin: 0 10px;
  border: 1px solid #eee;  
}
```

```html
<div layout>
    <div id="left">
        left
    </div>
    <div id="middle">
        middle
    </div>
    <div id="right">
        right
    </div>
</div>
```

---

*Side note:* nobody seems to have told you the horizontal bar you're trying to achieve was what the rest of the world was trying to avoid when they invented responsive layouts. It's considered really bad user experience and Google lowers the rank of websites that do not feature responsive layouts.
Long story short, it will be losing you (or the client) serious money. The more important the website, the more important the loss. A better user experience would be to transform left and right sidebars into swipe-able drawers on small devices.